# Recuperar resultado de stock procedure en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure

Estimados como puedo hacer para recuperar el contenido de un stock procedure en mysql.
Estoy usando este codigo pero me devuelve lo siguiente,

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(153) [1]=> float(8800) [2]=> int(1) } }
```

el out del sp es correcto pero quisiera poder recorrerlo en php como variables y asi hacer alguna accion o poder hacer json para pasarlo a java como resultado.

```
  //introducir el código aquí
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DBservidor, $DBusuario, $DBpass, $DBbase_datos);
              if($mysqli->connect_error){

                die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);

              }
                  mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");

// le paso a mano para probar un id y un valor y me devuelve correctamente esas 3 salidas
             $sql="call pedidos.SP_guardo_pedido(3, 15,@NuevoIDPedido,@Valor,@SeModifico);";
             if (!($sentencia = $mysqli->prepare($sql))) {
                echo "Falló la preparación: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
            }

            if (!$sentencia->execute()) {
                echo "Falló la ejecución: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
            }


             do {
                if ($resultado = $sentencia->get_result()) {
//aca devuelve x pantalla array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(153) [1]=> float(8800) [2]=> int(1) } }
// quisiera poder recorrerlo en un variable 
                    var_dump(mysqli_fetch_all($resultado));
                    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
                } else {
                    if ($sentencia->errno) {
                        echo "Store failed: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
                    }
                }
            } while ($sentencia->more_results() && $sentencia->next_result());

            mysqli_close($mysqli); 
            ?>
```

Comment: Si el dato que obtienes es correcto y es para devolverlo a otro sitio no veo por qué quieres recorrerlo. Si es para convertirlo en un JSON, puedes usar `json_encode` por ejemplo y devolver el objeto codificado como JSON. Si es para devolver a otro sitio, deberías dar coherencia a tu código. O sea, en vez de tantos `echo` preparar un array con una clave `error` dentro. Así, haya éxito o error, estarás siempre devolviendo un array convertido a JSON. Luego en el destino podrás verificar si el JSON tiene o no una clave `error` y mostrar qué error fue, o leer los datos si fue exitoso.

Comment: El problema que cuando quiero pasarlo a un array para procesar el resultado en php hago esto  $volvio[][]=mysqli_fetch_all($resultado) ;
                     echo $volvio[0][0];   y me da el siguiente error Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\coralesXamp\zpruebaSP2.php on line 37
Array   la linea 37 es el echo  gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Es que tienes mucha confusión en tu código. Por ejemplo aquí: `mysqli_fetch_all($resultado)` ya estarías metiendo todos los datos en un array. Debes decidirte por qué método usar para meter los datos. Por ejemplo, si haces esto: `$arrDatos=mysqli_fetch_all($resultado);` ya tienes en `$arrDatos` un array con todos los resultados. Pero no puedes usar varios métodos `fetch` sobre el mismo resultado, pues el método `fetch` que uses, cualquiera que sea, vaciará el puntero con los datos y no volverás a encontrarlos con un segundo método `fetch` usado en ese mismo contexto, no sé si me entiendes.

Comment: Gracias ahora si , disculpa y muchas gracias por tu ayuda.